# Virtuemart 2 Order confirmation before payment

Tags: email, joomla, payment, virtuemart

I'm using VM 2.0.6 and Joomla 2.5 and the Multisafepay payment gateway.

Whenever a user puts a product in his cart, and clicks on checkout, the user is send to another page completely (Multisafepay's website, so not VM anymore) where he can select his desired payment option - same thing as paypal for example. But, at that time, Virtuemart is already sending an e-mail to the user confirming his order. That e-mail is saying: Thank you for your order blabla, the status of your order is ***blank***..

So, VM is already sending an e-mail before the user payed.

Does anybode relate to this or knows an answer?

Comment: I hope [Joomla specific-site on Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla?referrer=yk0tPuOiO7NTYIRQ038Yyw2) begins to work fast... It'll be very usefull for such Joomla-specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the point where an invoice copy is sent to the customer in the Store Configuration. Look for Configuration > check out > Default Order Status to send an invoice and make sure you have the Confirmed status chosen.

Comment: Hi Polished Geek, I get your point. But that's for invoices. I'm talking about order confirmations. VM sends an e-mail to the user even before he selected a payment method (let alone payed). The user should get an e-mail after he payed, not before :p BTW: this happens on all of my shops, even on a clean installation.

Answer (score 0):

VM 2.0.6 is working like this :

when the order is placed that means any one of the shipping and payment  method is selected.
and cart have valid data it will create the order and send an email to the user that mentioned
an order has been placed.
You can change 
the sending mail section if you need.
One function name with notifyemail (iam not sure the name but it start with notify) in the path:
administrator/components/com_virtuemart/models/orders.php
you can check all your required things like shipping /payment methods are selected before calling this function.
the function should be initiate from cart.php controller in front end.

Comment: Hi, Jobin. That does sound right. And I realy don't mind the user gets an e-mail before he payed. But, standard, it should say: "The status of your order is Pending". Now it says nothing in the order status, and also the e-mail subject isn't translating (it just says the define state, like COM_VIRTUEMART_MAIL_SUBJ_SHOPPER_ without the P or C. BTW: With "sends to another page", I mean another website totally, not the VM page to select a payment, but the payment providers' website.

Comment: Hai Don Munter, did you check the order is placed in DB ? Also why your trying to payment section in another sites . try to create plugin for payment and manage with in the site.You can block the mail sending section and order create section with some customization of code if you required.

Comment: Hi Jobin, it's not for my self. It's for a client who owns 5 webshops. They already do their payment by another party. It's still not fixed though, so I'm trying to find a way to disable Virtuemart e-mails. (Except for the "Shipped" status, if that's possible).

Comment: Yes you can.In the order.php file in admin model section .one function is there "notifyemail" to customer this one is sending email you can put your custom condition their.